# How To skip Empty Rows in a PHP Table

Tags: php, html

I'm trying combine a table where fixtures are under their respective leagues [Headers] but i'm having a problem with the empty rows appearing in my table as its showing the empty rows instead of ignoring them

please check through the three pictures on how i want to shape my table:

[SQL Table With Empty Cells In COL 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmcId.png)

[HTML Table With Empty Rows Under Every Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXpRq.png)

[How I want My Table To Look Like after skipping empty Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXqaN.png)

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
    


<table class="Fixtures" border="1">


<tr>
    <thead>

    <th>League / Match</th>

    </thead>
</tr>

<br>

<tr>
    <th class="League ">Premier League</th>
</tr>

<tr >
    <td>Arsenal - Man united</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Chelsea - Newcastle</td>
</tr>




<th class="League">Spain La Liga</th>

<tr>
 <td>Barcelona - Real Madrid</td>   
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Sevilla - Real Sociedad</td>   
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Alaves - Cadiz</td>    
</tr>



<th class="League">Allsvenskan</th>

<tr>
 <td>Elfsborg - Varberg</td>   
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Kalmar - Varnamo</td>   
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Malmo FF - Helsingborg</td>    
</tr>



</table>








</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you instead post your desired HTML, and not a picture of it. If we can't agree on the HTML, we can't agree on the PHP that generates it.

Comment: Okay, I re-posted The Whole HTML

Comment: I'm skipping PHP completely for now. You should be able to make some sample HTML, no PHP, no JS, that renders how you want. Once we can see that we can templatize it to PHP.

Comment: Okay, Now that i have given you the code, Please help how to skip the empty rows, seems to be that there is no solution for this??

Comment: As I keep saying, PHP creates HTML. If you don't know the HTML that you want to create to begin with, we can't instruct PHP on how to generate it. We don't want pictures. You should be able to write regular boring old HTML that looks how you want it to. Once that's done, we can apply PHP to loop through things. If you are unable to produce HTML that looks how you want it to, that's a totally different question. If there's any PHP or JavaScript in what you post, my comment will be the same.

Comment: I Created An Html of how i want it to look like, what is the step forward

Comment: Thank you, that helps greatly! My next question is if you can confirm that this is what your data basically looks like? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0e651/1. I'm hoping it **isn't**, but that is what appears in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same,what should I do to avoid those empty spaces between premier league and spain la liga, when you try to combine them the empty spaces turn into empty rows and affect the php table

Comment: Before going too far with PHP, that is a pretty **unsafe** structure for your database and it can be broken trivially. See this for [two versions](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0e651/2). Your structure, as-is, cannot be inserted into except at the end. To make any inserts into the "middle" you'd need to manually delete all things after, insert, and then re-add. I would recommend adjusting your database before continuing. You want sane structure, not visually appealing structure. If your data looks like how you want it to render, you usually have a problem.

Comment: Instead, this is the version that most people would agree would be the better schema, or at least the start of one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/337b42a/7. If there's a specific order, it is common to add an `order_by` column, otherwise you can insert and update very easily.

Comment: Once you do all of that, you can keep track of the league and detect when it changes: https://3v4l.org/qZ5EH

Comment: My data imports from a csv file to SQL ,I  don't have to write down leagues and teams one by one, I understand most of the instructions you have given me here, I Have Now Changed My Table [COL 1] now doesn't have spaces, please give me steps on how to connect  https://3v4l.org/qZ5EH to my csv rather writing down data one by one

Comment: I need https://3v4l.org/qZ5EH to dynamically import from the database the code seem to be manual

Comment: The code is manual, but it should map to your query generally. Where I have an array called `$data` that I'm iterating over using `foreach`, you have an array from `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`. Inside of that, both of our code examples have a variable called `$row` that behaves the same.

Comment: If I may ask how do I assign a button to:  echo '<tr><th>' . $row["COL 1"] . '</th></tr>', PHP_EOL;

Comment: “How do I assign a button”, I’m not really sure what you are asking. Is it still specific to the original problem you were having or has that been solved and you are now doing something related, but different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding them, you can just skip them:

```php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!$row["COL 1"] && !$row["COL 2"]){
        continue;
    }
    // Your other code here

}
```

Comment: Its Still Giving Spaces between the leagues and the match

Comment: Good Day, I tried this code but its still giving empty headers [COL 1]  and whenever i edit it and remove COL 2 it seems to work but looses position where headers are supposed to cut in,please help

Comment: `<th>` is most commonly used as a column header, but if you output it in a loop that generally implies a row header, so I'm not really clear on your intention. Can you update your original question with a sample of the actual HTML (redacted if necessary) that you want to create in PHP? Use this for a reference if it is helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th